# Change function on Select

Tags: javascript

Continue from [change 3 dropdown values through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079113/change-3-dropdown-values-through-javascript), Just need to show the

```
function changeprice1(id){
```

On select of second dropdown i.e. `Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting`. What to do now, i am getting out of thinking now. Any Help in `jS` ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeprice(id){

var value = id;

if(value == ""){
    document.getElementById('price').value="";
alert("Please select one valid word count");

return false;
}
if(value == "Lessthan1000"){
var newprice = "USD 290";
}
if(value == "Lessthan2000"){
var newprice = "USD 540";
}
if(value == "Lessthan4000"){
var newprice = "USD 1050";
}
if(value == "Lessthan6000"){
var newprice = "USD 1900";
}
var eprice = newprice;

document.getElementById('price').value = eprice;

}

function changeprice1(id){

var value = id;

if(value == ""){
    document.getElementById('price').value="";
alert("Please select one valid word count");

return false;
}
if(value == "ReLessthan1000"){
var newprice = "USD 390";
}
if(value == "ReLessthan2000"){
var newprice = "USD 690";
}
if(value == "ReLessthan4000"){
var newprice = "USD 1600";
}
if(value == "ReLessthan6000"){
var newprice = "USD 2900";
}
var eprice = newprice;

document.getElementById('price').value = eprice;

}</script>
```

Here is the first dropdown

```
<select name="sp" id="sp" class="servicecategory">
<option value="" selected>Please Select...</option>
<option value="Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Writing" <?php if($servicename == "Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Writing"){ echo(" selected=\"selected\""); } ?>>Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Writing </option>
<option value="Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting" <?php if($servicename == "Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting"){ echo(" selected=\"selected\""); } ?>>Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting</option>
</select>
```

Here is the Second Dropdown ---

```
<select name="sp" id="sp" class="servicecategory" onChange="changeprice(this.value)">
<option value="" selected>Please Select...</option>
<option value="Lessthan1000">1 - 1000 words</option>
<option value="Lessthan2000">1001 - 2000 words</option>
<option value="Lessthan4000">2001 - 4000 words</option>
<option value="Lessthan6000">4001 - 6000 words</option>
</select>
```

This is the price area where the price is showing atlast

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="right">Price:</td>
<td width="5"></td>
<td valign="top" align="left"><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" readonly="" size="20"><br />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you put the script and html code part?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079113/change-3-dropdown-values-through-javascript

Comment: ok I've seen it. Can you tell me what do you really want to do with your first dropdown named 'sp'. It is not clear to me what you really want to do because your 2nd dropdown is working perfectly

Comment: Yes sure, i have two Services, one for Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting and Second is for Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Writing, Right, on this, we have two packages for both the services. We need to show the price for each Services once the user will select the 2 Drodpown because the packages changes for 1--1000 words and so on.. Got ?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well. It would be great if you had a link to the page so I can see the entire code. That would really help someone with providing you a solution.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question, can you please look out, i need to change the `function changeprice1(id)` and `function changeprice1(id)`
 on each 1 select dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function changeprice(id)
    {

        var value = id;
        selectedmenu=document.getElementById("sp").value
        if(selectedmenu == "select"){

        alert("Please select one valid word count");
        fnc();
        return false;
        }
        if(selectedmenu=='Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Writing')
            if(value == "Lessthan1000"){
            var newprice = "USD 290";
            }
            if(value == "Lessthan2000"){
            var newprice = "USD 540";
            }
            if(value == "Lessthan4000"){
            var newprice = "USD 1050";
            }
            if(value == "Lessthan6000"){
            var newprice = "USD 1900";
            }
            var eprice = newprice;

            document.getElementById('price').value = eprice;
        if(selectedmenu=='Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting')
        {
            if(value == "Lessthan1000"){
                var newprice = "USD 390";
                }
                if(value == "Lessthan2000"){
                var newprice = "USD 690";
                }
                if(value == "Lessthan4000"){
                var newprice = "USD 1600";
                }
                if(value == "Lessthan6000"){
                var newprice = "USD 2900";
                }
                var eprice = newprice;

                document.getElementById('price').value = eprice;

        }
    }


    function fnc()
    {
        document.getElementById("select").selected=true;
    }
    </script>

    <select name="sp" id="sp" class="servicecategory" onchange="fnc()">
        <option value="select"  selected>Please Select...</option>
        <option value="Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Writing" >Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Writing</option>
        <option value="Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting" >Medical and Biomedical Manuscript Rewriting</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Word_Count" id="Word_Count" onChange="changeprice(this.value)">
        <option value="select" id="select">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="Lessthan1000">1 - 1000 words</option>
        <option value="Lessthan2000">1001 - 2000 words</option>
        <option value="Lessthan4000">2001 - 4000 words</option>
        <option value="Lessthan6000">4001 - 6000 words</option>
    </select>

    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="right">Price:</td>
        <td width="5"></td>
        <td valign="top" align="left"><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" readonly="" size="20"><br /></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: If javascript is off in any browser...
the price will not show on selecting any service or word count

so,

how the Price and its textbox under "WORK DETAILS" should be hidden in form if javascript is off. ANy help?